# Constructing features from k-means

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, unsupervised-learning, feature-engineering

I would like to construct features from the result of apply k-means clustering to construct features of my data that I can later use for a classifier.

Assume I have fixed the $k$ (e.g. 5) and performed the clustering. Then I could use

1. the indicator of the cluster
2. the center of the cluster

as new features. What else is done in practice? I read about using the distance to the cluster centers as feature - can we find any reference for this?

Comment: It sounds a bit as if you are asking: "Which methods exists in classification and clustering?". As you know, that is a field with a vast quantity of methods, theories, articles, do's, don't. I think it would be a good idea to narrow down your question

Comment: @KenS. Thanks for your comment. I mean: what is usually done with kmeans. There are people out there with more experience than I have. What feature do the extract from kmeans if the goal is classification. Is this that broad? Would you still recommend to change the wording?

Comment: Am I right that you want to do clustering in order to create new features for the data in order to improve the classification results you want to do later?

Comment: @stats0007 exactly!

Comment: I feel this question isn't clear enough. What is meant exactly under "feature construction" in the present context?

Comment: @ttnphns as far as know this jus known as feature engineering. One strategy is to use the result of some clustering algorithm to define new features. I am asking what people do in the case of k-means...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a [great paper](https://www-cs.stanford.edu/~acoates/papers/coatesng_nntot2012.pdf) relating k-means with sparse coding of features, and how to address some of its weaknesses to produce good features. Even through it is focused on the particular case of image processing, it has valuable advice for the general case (how to do prewhitening to decorrelate data and so on).

Finally, it is well known that algorithms like kmeans and knn which (in its original formulation) use euclidean distance as a metric, perform poorly in a high dimensional setting. Here there is an importance [reference](https://bib.dbvis.de/uploadedFiles/155.pdf) addressing this point.

Edit: I came across this (IMHO *really* interesting) paper [**Deterministic** Feature Selection for k-Means Clustering](http://boutsidis.org/Boutsidis_IEEE_IT_13a.pdf), which provides a deterministic algorithms with theoretical analysis and **performance warranties**. See also some of the references therein, specially those by the first author.

Just to make one thing clear: what is the problem you are addressing (number of samples, dimensionality, etc)?. The motivation for feature selection in this paper is the poor performance of k-means in high dimensional space.
Often one assumption is made: only a few of the many features are relevant. Many approaches are suboptimal in some way: like greedy search and randomized search, and not all have warranties on their performance.
So what you do is iterate over a number of trials/alternative heuristics until you find a satisfactory result.

So in case you need to build new features, you could try to generate new, sensible features and then perform feature selection on whole set of features.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I knew the first paper. Is there anything in 'classical' classification (just numerical inputs)? The pictures are transformer to numerical inputs too...I know..

Comment: +1. But how does feature selection (a subset selected) is feature construction (new derived features created)?

Answer (score 4):

Basically there is no you must add this or this.....you actually should add features that verifiable improve your classification.

You can be creative here and try several things.

E.g. you can create statistics for variables (mean, sd,...) for each cluster and add these. You can also then add the difference to this new mean / median /... for example.

Also adding cluster 'quality measures' might be an idea, like
Intra cluster distance for each cluster,....

You can also try different clustering methods to create additional features.

Keep in mind, just creating these variables is not everything, you also have to check if your classification improves.

From my own experience:
Most of the times I could not improve classification results with new features created by clustering (but this is of course highly dataset dependent)

Another important thing: 
Make sure you do not include the target variable of your later on testset for classification in the clustering. This will give misleading results of classification performance.